# How can Netbeans 7.0 Beta tail Symfony (webapp) and Apache logs?

Tags: netbeans, logging, tail

I'd like to use **Netbeans 7.0** to tail 1 or more logs (especially Symfony app logs, but also, why not, local and custom Apache logs.

Searching didn't help... Could you ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "Tail File Module"?

This module provides an option (Tools -> Tail File ...) to tail a selected file and display the data in a tab within the Output window of the IDE.

http://sites.google.com/site/roguexz2/netbeans

Answer (score 0):

It is better to tail logs outside your IDE. Just use tail -f filename in a console.
If you are on windows, install cygwin (http://cygwin.org). It is unix emulator for windows platform.

Comment: I am not asking what's best to do, but HOW I can do something. Sorry, but this clearly doesn't answer my question. I do know tail -f. That's clearly not the point of this thread. But thanks.